# How to add specified styles(text which will be promptly visible after applying opacity) while clicking on a thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap.js@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
   var data = [
    { src: "..", title: "Image 1"},
    { src: "..", title: "Image 2"},
    { src: "..", title: "Image 3"}
   ];


   $(document).ready(function () {
     var $thumbs = $(".thumbnails");
     
     // dynamically add thumbnails to page
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $thumbs.append('<a href="#" class="thumbnail" alt="' + data[i].title + '"><img src="' + data[i].src + '" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>');
     }
   });
  </script>
     
</head>

<body>
  <!--thumbnail section-->
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row add-bottom text-center thumbnails">
    </div>
  </section>
  
</body>

</html>
```

I want to apply opacity and some text while clicking on an image thumbnail as shown in the image below.How would I go for doing the same?

[image: thumbs]

I have written the following code for implementing this, but I am not getting desired result

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <style>
   img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index:-1;
   }
   </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("img").click(function(){
    $(this).text("Hello");
   });
  });
  </script> 
  
</head>
<body>
 <img src=".." width="440" height="440">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know how the following can be done for dynamically added thumbnails (shown in the above code)?

Comment: Show what you've tried, post some code atleast on what you've..

Comment: @ND `$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).text("Hello");
   });` will not display `"Hello"` at `<img>` element. See [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) _"Permitted content  None, it is an empty element."_

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/9tnzqbgw/3/

HTML

```
<div class="imageContainer">
<div class="textContainer">
    <h1>Spider Man</h1>
    <span>This is test</span>
</div>
<img id="img1" src="http://images.indianexpress.com/2015/07/spiderman-new.jpg" width="500px" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $(".imageContainer img").on("click", function(e) {
     if (!$(this).closest(".imageContainer").hasClass("greyOut")) {
         $(this).closest(".imageContainer").addClass("greyOut");
         $(this).closest(".imageContainer").find(".textContainer").show();
     } else {
         $(this).closest(".imageContainer").removeClass("greyOut");
         $(this).closest(".imageContainer").find(".textContainer").hide();
     }
 });
```

CSS

```
.imageContainer{ position : relative}
.textContainer { position : absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
padding:10px; color:white;text-align:center;display:none;
}
.greyOut{
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set parent element of `<img>` element as `<figure>`, use `data-*` attribute at `<figure>` element to store text to display, `css` `:after`, `content`, `opacity`; `.add()`, `.toggleClass()` at `js` to toggle styles of `<figure>` and `<img>` at click on `img` element

```js
$(".image").click(function() {
  $(this).add(this.parentElement).toggleClass("clicked");
})
```

```css
figure {
  margin: 0px;
}
figure.clicked:after {
  color: sienna;
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-title);
  font-size: 16px;
  z-Index: 1;
  padding: 4px;
  left: 20px;
}
.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: olive;
}
.clicked,
:not(.clicked) {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.clicked:not(figure) {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<figure data-title="I'm a Title 
I'm a Description">
  <img class="image" />
</figure>
```